# Shortest distance between a point an a non linear surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to find  the shortest distance between a point $P(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ and the surface $z=xy$.

Could somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3):

A point in the surface has the form $(x,y, xy)$. The square of the distance from this point to $P$ is given by: $$f(x,y) = (x - p_1)^2 + (y - p_2)^2 + (xy - p_3)^2$$
Now you can find the critical points by solving: $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 0 \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$$

Comment: That will provide only critical points.
Don't we need to find anything else?

Answer (score 3):

$z = f(x,y) = xy$. Note that
$$
d = \sqrt{(x - p1)^2 + (y - p2)^2 + (xy - p3)^2}
$$
Thus, we minimize the function
$$
f(x,y) = (x - p_1)^2 + (y - p2)^2 + (xy - p3)^2
$$
The partial derivatives are
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2(x - p1) + 2(xy - p3)y = 0\\
\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 2(y - p2) + 2(xy - p3)x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
The solution of this system gives candidates the points which minimizes the distance.

Comment: so it's not just one point with the shortest distance? is it a surface?

Comment: @JohnP You have a homogeneous linear system in 2 unknowns. The solution cannot be a surface.

Comment: I see thanks,  but how such a complex equation can be solved?

Comment: Isolating y in the second equation and substituting in the first, after some algebraic manipulations, we obtain an equation of the fifth degree which must be solved numerically.

Comment: say p=(0,0,0) then we have x+xy^2=0 and y+x^2y=0 so x=0 and y=0, right?